# How to open Stocks app on ios from my app?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, stock

I know that popular apps usually have own links, f.e. `whatsapp://app` will open WhatsApp or if you have Instagram installed, it will open `instagram.com/...` links.
In my app, I would like to open the iOS "Stocks" app (it is installed by default). Do they have deep linking and can I for example in my app open the link like `stocks://AAPL` to navigate to the Apple stock prices page?

**UPD:** I've found that `stocks://` really opens the Stocks app :)
but now the question still is how to open the exact company in it

Answer (score 0):

Found that `https://stocks.apple.com/symbol/AAPL` will do what I want :)